# compdata: relationship between :+: and Subsume

Tags: haskell

I've been reading "Data Types a la Carte" and trying to follow along with

`:set -XTypeOperators
:m Data.Comp.Ops
:m Data.Comp
type X' a = [] :+: Maybe
type X a = Term (X' a)`

So, X Int should be a list or a maybe of Int. But nothing that I've tried has resulted in me being able to create a value of type X Int. I've also tried the smart constructors and they've complained that there's no Subsume relationship available. Looking at hackage, there doesn't appear to be one. Could someone explain how I can square this circle?

Comment: Your GHCi session all ended up on one line, making it quite hard to read. Could you fix that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood, `X Int` contains no values of type `Int`. The type alias `X'` does not use `a` in the right hand side; therefore, it must be a phantom type. The type `X a`, for any `a`, contains trees with either *zero or more nodes* (due to `[]`) or *zero or one* node (due to `Maybe`). Note, that neither has data at the nodes, or leaves. If you want this tree structure, with data at each 'branch', you must add a constant at each branch:

```
type X' a = K a :*: ([] :+: Maybe)
```

Where `newtype K a x = K a`. In fact, this concept of adding a 'constant annotation' to a signature is so common that compdata has a special construct for it, `f :&: e`, which is isomorphic to `f :*: K e`. Then construct it like so:

```
import Data.Comp
import Data.Comp.Ops
import Data.Comp.Show
import Data.Comp.Sum

type X' a = ([] :+: Maybe) :&: a
type X a = Term (X' a)

listNode :: a -> [X a] -> X a 
listNode x xs = Term $ Inl xs :&: x  

mayNode :: a -> Maybe (X a) -> X a 
mayNode x mx = Term $ Inr mx :&: x 

test = listNode 1 
         [ mayNode 2 Nothing
         , mayNode 3 $ Just $ 
           mayNode 10 $ Just $ 
             listNode 4 
               [ listNode 10 [] 
               , mayNode 1 Nothing 
               ]
          ]
```